# Repeating posts in blogger

Tags: navigation, blogs, blogger, posts, blogger-dynamic-views

Hi friends this is my blog http://hamaracinema2009.blogspot.in/
recently i have added the template iam attaching you can view it

my problem is posts are repeating again and again in each page

you can visit my blog by clicking 1st page and 2nd page u can able to understand they are reapeating i have searched on google that we should removie either

or

but i have only this code in my blog

i had removed it so when i opened my blog the post page is completely dissappeard and side bar appeared in center so i again added

how to solve this a great headache to me friends as u can see the template i have attached to that plz view and suggest me with our precious suggestions thanks waiting for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Template > Edit HTML.
DO NOT tick the Expand Widget Templates checkbox.
Find and delete the following line in your HTML code:
1

or
1

Click SAVE TEMPLATE button to save.
You will be asked whether to keep the widget or delete it. Choose to delete by clicking DELETE WIDGETS button.
Done.